# How to Programmatically Take Photos While Recording Video

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, avfoundation

The iPhone 5S is capable of taking pictures while recording video and I am trying to figure out how I would do this programatically. I know I would be utilizing AVFoundation, however, I couldn't find anything in the [programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW26) regarding this. I have also checked the [sample projects](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code) (AVFoundation-related) and it doesn't look like there is anything there that does what I am looking for. if you could help point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: means you want capture photo from video (like video cover image) ??

Comment: No, thanks for asking. On the iPhone 5S in the camera app, when doing a video recording, you may take pictures (by tapping a white button off to the side). I want to achieve this sort of thing in my app, programatically. I will even go so far to consider private APIs.

Answer (score 6):

Actually you can do it with any device that can record video:

- Create and configure a `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`.
- Add it to your `AVCaptureSession`.
- Add a `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate`.
- Implement `captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:` in the delegate and get the image with `imageFromSampleBuffer:`.

Some similar code can be found [here](https://github.com/CyberAgent/iOS-NBUImagePicker/blob/7df84e55920b5bbdc85db25a96ed19b393060e46/Source/Camera/NBUCameraView.m#L680), where images are captured at a given interval, but you only want one image.

Comment: Can't we use this process for getting chunks of video clips while recording the same video?

Answer (score 3):

In iOS7 there has a new api to capture UIView, we can get image and do something.

eg:

```
UIView+Screenshot.h
-(UIImage *)convertViewToImage;

UIView+Screenshot.m

-(UIImage *)convertViewToImage
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
    [self drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

Apple's Document: [drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#jumpTo_81)

Comment: Wow! This new method really works with video, unlike the old one [CALayer renderInContext:]

Answer (score 1):

Through AVCaptureSession you can easily achieve iPhone 5S in the camera app functionality.
In your view touch event:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection "
```

You can get current frame on above delegate method and save it in your gallery.

Please go through below link:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/RosyWriter/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Rivera's answer ! You are going to need AV

And this is how I do it after the hole AV stuff

```
CGImageRef bigImage = image.CGImage;
CGRect rectImage = CGRectMake(self.scannArea.origin.x*widhtRatio,
                              self.scannArea.origin.y*heightRatio - 50,
                              self.scannArea.size.width*widhtRatio,
                              self.scannArea.size.height*heightRatio);
CGImageRef part = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(bigImage, rectImage);
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum([UIImage imageWithCGImage:part], nil, nil, nil);

image = [self drawImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"overlaygraphic.png"] 
                inImage:image 
                atPoint:CGPointMake(self.scannArea.origin.x*widhtRatio, 
                                    self.scannArea.origin.y*heightRatio - 50)];
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
```

if you want to see the hole sample np. I will upload my class